# Get all meeting rooms from outlook API

Tags: outlook-restapi

I'm trying to use the outlook API to return all meeting rooms from an account in a list.
Is this possible? I can't find it anywhere in the documentation. 
Which api call do I have to make?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Outlook API itself does not have this ability currently. However, we are planning to release a beta API for this in the coming weeks. We'll announce it on our [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/).